# clearAnimation() and onAnimationEnd() in android

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I am using multiple animations and playing animations one after other. Currently using onAnimationEnd() to play animations one after other. In case of onTouch, I need to stop the animation and need to set different bitmap to imageview in touch location. Currently  using below code but facing problems in case of clearAnimation().

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {      

switch(event.getAction()) {

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

    imageArray[g_animCount - 1].clearAnimation();   

    break;

default:
   break;

}

return true; // indicate event was handled
}



   @Override
   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    layout.removeView(imageArray[g_animCount - 1]);

    if ( (g_animCount < count))
    {               
        startNextAnimation();
    }
    else
    {
        g_animCount = 0;
        isBegin = false;
    }
```

}

### Problems and queries:

After clear animation, I could see image again at the beginning location, how to keep it at touch location ? tried setFillAfter(true) but no use.

How to define onAnimationEnd() in case to play animations one after other ? do we need to remove imageview?

Without clearAnimation() I do not have any problems but it does not solve my problem. Kindly correct my code.

Answer (score 0):

1) to keep the ImageView to the new location you have to specify the new coordinates.
You can do it in this way:

```
MarginLayoutParams l = new MarginLayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());
l.leftMargin = left;
l.topMargin = top;
v.setLayoutParams(l);
```

v is your ImageView, left and top are the coordinates (x,y) to place the view on the screen. The parent should be a RelativeLayout.

2) it's better to start all the animation in sequence avoid calling new start in the callback methods (onAnimationEnd, etc). You don't need to remove the view if you have to use it later in the flow

Answer (score 0):

My reply may be a bit out of date, but better later than never.

I also noticed this nasty bug: when you call `cancelAnimation`, the `AnimationListener.onAnimationEnd` is called, however the view stays and there is no "legal" ways to hide it (tried remove view from layout, set visibility to `View.INVISIBLE`, even negative `marginTop` and `marginBottom` - nothing works). The bug is present with Andoid 2.3 and Android 4.0. It doesn't turn up with KitKat, presumably has been fixed.

Here's the good news. I've found a work around with `ImageView`: in `AnimationListener.onAnimationEnd` I say `animationView.setImageDrawable(null)` and the view disappears. Hopefully this will help someone.